# "Unknown arguments specified" error when building ESP-IDF project using CMake

Tags: c, cmake, esp-idf, espressif-idf, esp-idf-sys

While I am compiling the hello world example on ESP-IDF on Windows. I got this error:

```
Compiler supported targets: 
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
CMake Error at C:/Espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v5.1.2/components/xtensa/project_include.cmake:17 (if):
See also "C:/Espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v5.1.2/workspace/hello_world/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  if given arguments:

    "NOT" "(" "Generic" "STREQUAL" "Generic" "AND" "MATCHES" "xtensa" ")"

  Unknown arguments specified
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v5.1.2/tools/cmake/build.cmake:398 (include)
  C:/Espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v5.1.2/tools/cmake/build.cmake:620 (__build_process_project_includes)
  C:/Espressif/frameworks/esp-idf-v5.1.2/tools/cmake/project.cmake:547 (idf_build_process)
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (project)
```

I tried to uninstall the environment and reinstall it to check if there are any missing configuration, but the same results.

Comment: The [referenced code line](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/v5.1.2/components/xtensa/project_include.cmake#L17) is `if(NOT (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL "Generic" AND ${dump_machine} MATCHES xtensa))`. The variable `dump_machine` is empty (exactly its value is printed after "Compiler supported targets:", so "if" expression  becomes invalid. You may report that to the project developers.